# How to start a shell script within "expect script"?

Tags: expect

In this expect script there will be no ssh server connected, I just want to execute a ".sh" file locally, is that possible?

For instance:

```
#!/bin/expect

command "xxx.sh" # a command which starts a certain shell script
```

Also, is it possible to execute a expect script within a expect script?

For instance:

```
#!/bin/expect

command "xxx.exp" # a command which starts a certain expect script
```

Any help?

Comment: Why does it matter whether there's an SSH server connected? Expect has no special relationship with SSH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command in Expect to run a shell command is `spawn`.

```
#!/bin/expect
spawn command arg1 arg2 ...
```

`command` can be any program -- a binary executable, a shell script, another expect script, etc. So you can do:

```
spawn xxx.sh
```

or:

```
spawn xxx.exp
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to **interact** with this script, use `spawn xxx.sh`

If you just need to run it and capture the output, use `set output [exec xxx.sh]`

Expect is an extension of the Tcl language, so you would be well served to go through the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).